# Can customers reorder configurable products?

Tags: product, configurable-product

Does anyone know how you can get it so that configurable products can be reordered as well as simple products?

I have to set up a product that a customer will pick size, colour and material. But it will often be the procurement department ordering and they will just want to reorder the product again.

Is this possible?

Comment: This default magenot feature.Is this not happening on your magento

Comment: Hi, it is only working on simple products for me. Our configurable product involves a file upload (for artwork), and this seems to prevent the reorder function from working.